# UIImageの画像読み込み【UIImage(contentsOfFile:)】が動作してくれない

Tags: swift

UIImageの画像読み込みの際に`Bundle.main.path`で指定する`UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`かファイル名で指定する`UIImage(named:)`があると思うのですが、`UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`の方がうまく動作してくれません。
メソッド`loadPhoto(name:)`のどこが間違えているのでしょうか？

```swift
func loadImage(_ name: String) -> UIImage?{
    if let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "png"){
        print("UIImage(contentsOfFile:)で画像生成しました")
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)!
    } else {
        print("UIImage(named:)で画像生成しました")
        return UIImage(named: name)!
    }
}
```

全体のコード

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func tapButton() {
        if let image: UIImage = self.loadImage("Correct") {
            let width = self.view.frame.size.width
            let height = self.view.frame.size.height
            self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: width/2, height: height/2)
            self.imageView.center = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height/2)
            self.imageView.image = image
            
            self.view.addSubview(imageView)
        } else {
            print("画像が適用できません")
        }
    }
    
    func loadPhoto(_ name: String) -> UIImage?{
        if let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "png"){
            print("UIImage(contentsOfFile:)で画像生成しました")
            return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)!
        } else {
            print("UIImage(named:)で画像生成しました")
            return UIImage(named: name)!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: あなたのコードを試しました(`loadImage`か`loadPhoto`かわからないので両方)が、いずれも「UIImage(contentsOfFile:)で画像生成しました」と言うメッセージとともに画像が画面に表示されました。失敗しているのだとしたら、画像リソースをプロジェクトに追加するやり方がおかしいのではないですか?

Comment: 画像追加の正しい方法が、わかっていないのですが、画像の追加はAssets.xcassetsに表示されていれば問題ないでしょうか？

Comment: 問題あります。Assets.xcassets 内の画像には、`Bundle.main.path(forResource:ofType:)`ではアクセスできません。

Comment: 画像ファイルはViewController.swiftと同じ階層と、Assets.xcassetsに置いているのですが、どこに置けばいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 普通のソースファイルをプロジェクトにドラッグ&ドロップで付け加えるような手順で、プロジェクトに画像ファイルをコピーして下さい。簡単に回答の形で手順を書かせてもらいます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、大前提として、

1. `Bundle.path(forResource:ofType:)`でパスが取得できるのは、アプリケーションに「バンドル・リソース」として追加されているファイルだけです。
2. `UIImage.init(contentsOfFile:)`で画像が読み出せるのは、アプリ実行時にファイルとして、アプリから読み出せる場所にあるファイルだけです。

「バンドル・リソース」として追加したい画像は、ドラッグ&ドロップなどでプロジェクトに追加してください。

- Finderで画像のコピーのあるフォルダーを開いて、XcodeのProject navigator(画面左側)にドラッグするなどして、画像を追加してください。

[image: Xcode画面]

- 追加された画像をFile inspector(画面右側)で **Target Membership** にチェックが入っているのを確認してください。

---

Assets.xcassets の中身が、ビルドされた後にどんな形でアプリに組み込まれるのかは、実装上の詳細にあたる事柄で保証されていません。ネット上をよく探せばファイルとして読みだす方法が見つかるかもしれませんが、あまり積極的に利用しない方が良いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その方法でやっていたのですが、うまくいかず別の画像をイラストやからダウンロードして適用してみたら、うまくいったので、もしかしたら画像がpng形式だけど中身は違った？せいでうまくいかなかったのかもしれません。

Comment: `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`と`UIImage(named:)`とどちらを使った方がいいとかはありますか？

Comment: @zunda さん、Xcodeはちょっとした操作の違いで「同じことをやった」はずなのに、動いてくれないこともあるので、何が起こっていたのか推定するのは難しいですね。`UIImage(named:)`は「画像データがキャッシュに残る」(度々ロードする画像についてはロードは速いがメモリ使用量が増える)、「Assets.xcassets(アセットカタログ)に対応している」(解像度別の画像を持ったり、ローカライズが簡単)と言った特徴があります。ご自身の用途に合わせてきちんと使い分けると良いでしょう。